# change the calendar control in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, calendar-control

Is there a way to change the current calendar control in wpf or telerik? I am doing translation in my application. When I change language to Japanese, is there a way to include the Japanese calendar control instead of the English one.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Set the [`FrameworkElement.Language`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.language.aspx) property of your control or apply the xml:lang attribute to the XAML of your control. The value you have to set is `xml:lang="ja-JP".`

from **msdn** [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.globalization.cultureinfo)

For example,

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xml:lang="ja-JP"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Calendar />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, I have been looking for this for so long.